# How to add condition into new column that just added? -SQL-

Tags: sql

Query is below

```
select fname,lname,DATEDIFF(YY,birthdate,GETDATE()) as age from EMPLOYEE where age = 72
```

but there is an error says --> "Invalid column name 'age'.

How can i solve it? Thank you!

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you have to repeat the expression (from the `select`) to use it in the `where` clause:

```
select fname,lname,DATEDIFF(Year,birthdate,GETDATE()) as age 
from EMPLOYEE 
where DATEDIFF(Year,birthdate,GETDATE()) = 72
```

Unless using something like `cross apply()` to create the calculated field.

Comment: THANK YOU! Good Evening!

Answer (score 1):

My favorite way to do this in SQL Server uses a lateral join:

```
select e.fname, e.lname, v.age
from EMPLOYEE e cross apply
     (values (DATEDIFF(year, birthdate, GETDATE())) v(age)
where v.age = 72;
```

Notes:

- The more traditional ways of solving this use CTEs, subqueries, or repeat the expression.
- More importantly, you have a very arcane definition of age.  It is now 2017-04-05 where I am.  My your arithmetic, anyone born in 2016 would have an age of "1".

Answer (score 0):

Just repeat the expression in the `where` clause:

```
select fname,
    lname,
    DATEDIFF(YY, birthdate, GETDATE()) as age
from EMPLOYEE
where DATEDIFF(YY, birthdate, GETDATE()) = 72
```